# Drools: How to Declare and Assign Global

Tags: drools

I want to declare a global variable in a drools rule file (mvel).  This is because this global is used in all the rules as a parameter to another function.  I could easily pass this string explicitly in every call to the function, but this makes it hard if the string changes.

I thought I could do a:

```
global String someStr = "some string";
```

But on compile, I get:

```
[11,31]: [ERR 107] Line 11:31 mismatched input '=' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, import, global, declare, function, rule, query]'.
```

So obviously, I can't assign it this way.  Nor do I seem to be able to declare a class and a string in that class to reference through the class.

So I found I could so something that seems silly:

```
global String someStr;
rule "Initialize"
when
then
   someStr = "some string";
end
```

This seems to work, but, this will log every single time this rule matches (always) to just assign a global.

Is there a better way that I'm missing???

Comment: How about reading Section 7.5.2, Global, in the Drools manual? There may be other details you might need in your context, so I think it would be rewarding to read the documentation.

Comment: Do you think I would have posted without reading the manual first?  Come on.  The silly way to do it, a rule to execute as true, is straight from the manual!

Comment: Which manual, which section? You must be confusing things. - The statement "this will log every single time" is not correct.

Comment: You are asking "How to declare and assign a global". But your actual problem seems to be passing a string value to a function. For the first: see the manual. For the second: show the function and describe when and how it should be possible to change this parameter - at compile time, at runtime: once at start-up time, or many times depending on...? --- The quality of an answer depends on the quality of the question.

Comment: Again, no offense, nowhere have I stated that passing a string value to a function is an issue.  I simply asked how you declare and assign global value in a drools file.  Declaring a global is not a problem, assigning a global variable is a problem.  You cannot declare and assign at the same time, which means you have do assign it another way.

Comment: As for the statement, "it will log every single time" .... for the drools file execution, depending on the log level you are using (I want to catch executions of a rule that has a match), yes, any rule match will be logged as a MATCH.  So if I am making a run mode with that level of logging, an always true rule will log every time it matches (which is always).  And it is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using globals is a two step process. Declaration and assignment.

Declaration takes place in the rule file.

Assignment takes place at session level in the java code.

In the java code:

```
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    KieSession ks = kcontainer.newKieSession("test");
    ks.setGlobal("glist", list);
```

In the drl file:

```
global java.util.List glist;
```

Now this glist global variable which has values "a", "b", "c" can be used across all the rules in the drl file.

Comment: I should have update this a long time ago.  I did this a different way, but used a JSON structure and set it to the Kie session.  Very similar, both work.

Comment: how? can you share that code

Answer (score 0):

you can also define a function in the DRL

```
function String getParam(String name){
   return name.equals("x") ? "xValue" : "yValue";
}


.....
/// call it in you rule as below
.....

rule "my rule"
when 
then
  System.out.println(getParam("x"));
end
```